How to Automatically Analyze Word Frequency Across Multiple Included LaTeX Documents from a Main File
I am looking for an efficient way to analyze the frequency of certain words across a collection of LaTeX documents. I have a main.tex file that includes several other .tex files (using \include and \input). My objective is to count how often specific words appear across all these documents, excluding any text within comments, equations, etc.
While I am familiar with TeXcount and believe it could potentially be part of a solution (especially with its -inc option to handle included files), I am not necessarily fixed on using it if there are better alternatives. I am looking for any method that would allow me to automatically process main.tex and analyze word frequencies across all included documents without manually parsing each file or reinventing LaTeX parsing logic.
Here is a conceptual approach I am considering, but I am open to completely different strategies as well:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM I thought about using a script like this to process main.tex
REM and somehow extract word counts for specific words across all included documents.
texcount main.tex -inc <other options> | findstr /G:words_to_check.txt /L

echo Done.
endlocal

Could anyone suggest how to adapt this script or recommend a different tool or method that would achieve the desired result? I am particularly interested in any scripts, tools, or workflows that other LaTeX users have found effective for similar tasks.

I found a solution that perfectly meets my needs and wanted to share it here in case it helps anyone facing a similar challenge.
The key to analyzing word frequency across multiple LaTeX documents included from a main.tex file is the correct use of the TeXcount command. Here's the command that worked for me:
texcount main.tex -inc -total -brief -freq

This command configuration does the following:

-inc: Includes all files referenced by \input and \include commands in the analysis.
-total: Produces a total count for all included documents.
-brief: Provides a brief summary of the counts, which is ideal for a quick overview.
-freq: Lists the frequency of each word used in the documents, which is exactly what I needed.

To make this process seamless across different operating systems, I developed a simple CMD batch script for Windows and a Bash script for POSIX-compatible OSes (like macOS and Linux). You can find these scripts and more details on their usage in my GitHub repository here: avoid-gpt-phrases.
This repository contains a straightforward command-line tool designed to identify and avoid overused phrases, particularly those that are commonly found in AI-generated text. It's tailored to help LaTeX/TeX document writers recognize and reduce the use of repetitive phrases, enhancing the originality and quality of their work.
Feel free to check out the repository; I hope this tool also proves helpful to you!
